# How do you PM someone on freelancer.com?

Tags: freelancer.com

Seriously losing my mind here.

Very basic:

- Made a bid
- Bid was accepted
- I agreed to the accepted bid
- Want to send the guy a PM.

How in the blue blazes do I send this guy a message, or even show him the work? It's like... I've spent more time trying to do THAT than the actual work involved.

I'm not sure if I'm stupid, dreaming, drunk, high, in a coma, or... what exactly is going on here, but I feel slightly embarrassed that this is so hard to figure out.

Is it because I need to wait on the other party to take some sort of action? I can see no explanation in plain sight, or after searching around. I suspect this might be it, but nothing conclusively tells me that. But I still don't understand why I can't send the guy a PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no way to contact them first, and must indefinitely wait on them sending you a first message.

Meanwhile, the countdown starts when you accept the bid, and wait for them to send you a message.